# .gitignore files in parent folder

Tags: html, css, git

I have a folder structure like this:

```
folder 1
- folder 2
- - file.css
- - file.css
- folder 3
- - file.css
- folder 4
- - file.css
```

Is there a way to make git ignore all the `.css` files in `folder 1`? Without having to mention the children folders?

Comment: Just read the [.gitignore](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) documentation. There are too many ways to achieve it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ cat .gitignore
/folder 1/*.css
```

The `/` at the beginning [anchors the file names](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_pattern_format) to the root of the repository. A simple `*` matches only file names, not the `/` for sub-directories.

If `folder 1` is your git root folder, use

```
/*.css
```

For a folder named `.css` in your git root folder use

```
/.css
```

Comment: What about if css is a dot folder?

Answer (score 1):

css in folder1

```
/*.css
```

all css

```
*.css
```